# Refreshing picturebox stops other controls that need to redraw

Tags: c#, rotation

So I have this steering wheel control, and when I rotate it with the mouse and refresh the image it stops my other panel control from drawing its graph from updating/redrawing. Below is the code for rotating and redrawing the steering wheel.

```
private readonly Bitmap _originalHelmImage;
private Bitmap _newHelmImage;

private void HelmPb_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;
        PictureBox p = (PictureBox) sender;
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) p.Image;
        //GetPixel works on initial image, not stretched one.
        double ratio = (double) p.Image.Width/p.Width;
        //Ignore the non-helm portion of the helm.
        Color trans = bmp.GetPixel(Convert.ToInt32(ratio*e.X), Convert.ToInt32(ratio*e.Y));
        if (trans.A.Equals(0))
        {
            _dontTurn = true;
            return;
        }
        _offsetAngle = OffsetAngle() - _lastAngleTurn;
        _lastAngleTurn = 0;
        _dontTurn = false;
    }

    private double OffsetAngle()
    {
        int helmXMid = HelmPb.PointToScreen(Point.Empty).X + (HelmPb.Width / 2);
        int helmYMid = HelmPb.PointToScreen(Point.Empty).Y + (HelmPb.Height / 2);
        double angle = AngleFromPoints(MousePosition, new Point(helmXMid, helmYMid));
        return angle;
    }

private void HelmPb_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) || _dontTurn) return;
        double angle = OffsetAngle();
        float degrees = Convert.ToSingle(angle - _offsetAngle);
        //float diff = ((360 - degrees) - _deltaHelmTurn%360)%360;
        //float diff = (_lastAngleTurn - (degrees - 360)) % 360;
        double diff = 90 - angle;
        _deltaHelmTurn += Convert.ToSingle(diff - _lastAngleTurn);
        if (Math.Abs(_deltaHelmTurn) >= (_maxHelmTurn*360.0))
        {
            _deltaHelmTurn = Convert.ToSingle(_maxHelmTurn*360.0);
            degrees = 0;
        }
        _lastAngleTurn = Convert.ToSingle(degrees);
        _newHelmImage = RotateImage(_originalHelmImage, -degrees);
        HelmPb.Image.Dispose();
        HelmPb.Image = _newHelmImage;
        WaterDepthPlot.Invalidate();
        HelmPb.Refresh();
    }

double AngleFromPoints(Point pt1, Point pt2)
    {
        Point p = new Point(pt1.X - pt2.X, pt1.Y - pt2.Y);
        double alpha;
        if (p.Y == 0) alpha = p.X > 0 ? 0d : 180d;
        else
        {
            double f = 1d * p.X / (Math.Sqrt(p.X * p.X + p.Y * p.Y));
            alpha = Math.Acos(f) * 180d / Math.PI;
            if (p.Y > 0) alpha = 360d - alpha;
        }
        return alpha;
    }

 private Bitmap RotateImage(Bitmap b, float angle)
    {
        //Create a new empty bitmap to hold rotated image.
        Bitmap returnBitmap = new Bitmap(b.Width, b.Height);
        //Make a graphics object from the empty bitmap.
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(returnBitmap);
        //move rotation point to center of image.
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        g.TranslateTransform(b.Width/2F, b.Height/2F);
        //Rotate.
        g.RotateTransform(angle);
        //Move image back.
        g.TranslateTransform(-b.Width/2F, -b.Height/2F);
        //Draw passed in image onto graphics object.
        g.DrawImage(b, new PointF(0.0F, 0.0F));
        return returnBitmap;
    }
```

Below is the code for updating my graph. It is never ran when the steering wheel is being moved. Once the users stops moving, it will update. Is there a way for it to constantly update along with it? I tried throwing a refresh/invalidate of the panel into the mousemove event so whenever the wheel is refreshed, so is the graph; no luck. Any suggestions?

```
private void WaterDepthPlot_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(70, 75, 80));
        int xOffset = WaterDepthPlot.Location.X;
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, 0), new Point(WaterDepthPlot.Width, 0));
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, (WaterDepthPlot.Height/5)),
                            new Point(WaterDepthPlot.Width, (WaterDepthPlot.Height/5)));
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, (2*WaterDepthPlot.Height/5)),
                            new Point(WaterDepthPlot.Width, (2*WaterDepthPlot.Height/5)));
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, (3*WaterDepthPlot.Height/5)),
                            new Point(WaterDepthPlot.Width, (3*WaterDepthPlot.Height/5)));
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, (4*WaterDepthPlot.Height/5)),
                            new Point(WaterDepthPlot.Width, (4*WaterDepthPlot.Height/5)));
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, new Point((ThirdXScaleUnit.Location.X - xOffset), 0),
                            new Point((ThirdXScaleUnit.Location.X - xOffset),
                                      (WaterDepthPlot.Height + WaterDepthPlot.Location.Y)));
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, new Point((SecondXScaleUnit.Location.X - xOffset), 0),
                            new Point((SecondXScaleUnit.Location.X - xOffset),
                                      (WaterDepthPlot.Height + WaterDepthPlot.Location.Y)));
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, new Point((FirstXScaleUnit.Location.X - xOffset), 0),
                            new Point((FirstXScaleUnit.Location.X - xOffset),
                                      (WaterDepthPlot.Height + WaterDepthPlot.Location.Y)));
        pen = new Pen(Color.Firebrick);
        pen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dash;
        float[] dash = {3, 3};
        pen.DashPattern = dash;
        double diff = (double) WaterDepthPlot.Height/(5*_depthYScale);
        int alertDiff = (int)(_alertDepth * diff);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, new Point(0, alertDiff), new Point(WaterDepthPlot.Width, alertDiff));
        pen = new Pen(Color.White);
        GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
        if (_depthCurve.Count < 2) return;
        gp.AddCurve(_depthCurve.ToArray());
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, gp);
    }
```

Comment: You should be disposing your drawing objects.  Creating new bitmaps on every mouse move is expensive — try just using one bitmap and draw on that.

Comment: True, I made a global Bitmap and just update that each time. Didn't fix this problem but I see your point. @LarsTech

Comment: You should also post the AngleFromPoints function, too, but unless I'm missing something, it's those new bitmaps that are your problem.

Comment: I edited/posted it. Also edited with Bitmap change. @LarsTech

Comment: You're still creating images.  `using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.Helm))` looks unnecessary.  Just load that once in the constructor and use that image every time.  RotateImage would be the next culprit you didn't post the code for, but it's probably creating a new image, too.  How big are these images anyway?

Comment: Painting is a low priority operation.  When your code triggered by the mouse moves starts burning 100% core, it doesn't get around to doing the low priority tasks anymore.  No more paints.  Using Refresh() instead of Invalidate() made it worse.  Lots of ways to improve this, including not generating the bitmaps on-the-fly at all.  Do it up front when your program loads.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I can take out creating a new bitmap in the rotation function (which I posted) because multiple different controls use this and unless I make initial variables for every control and pass those in.. I guess I could do that.